# How should I debug VHDL error 10476 - type disagreement

Tags: vhdl

I don't understand what I should do .

Here is my code:

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all ;
use ieee.std_logic_signed .all ;

entity M is 
port(
        clk     : in  std_logic ;
        rst     : in  std_logic ;
        data    : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        CD      : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        s       : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0));

end entity ;

architecture beh of M is

signal com :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin 

code :process(clk,rst)

begin

    if (rst='1') then
      (others=>'0')<=data;
       --data<='0' !!! ;
       (others=>'0')<=CD;
       --"0000"<=CD ;
       s   <=(others=>'0');
     else
        for i in 0 to 3 loop 

          if (clk'event and clk='1')then 

               --for i in 0 to 3 loop 

                  com(i)<= not(CD(i)xor(data) ) ;
                  --s<=not(CD(i) xor (data));

           end if ;  
        end loop ;

    end if ;
    end process ;
    s<=com(i) ;
    end architecture ;
```

This is my problem :

> Error (10476): VHDL error at M.vhd(39): type of identifier "data" does
>   not agree with its usage as "std_ulogic" type

Comment: How do you xor 1 bit with 2 bits? `data` is a 2-bit wide vector.

Comment: The problem here isn't strictly `xor`ing 2 bits with 1 bit (which is supported in VHDL-2008) - it's assigning the result to a 1-bit slice. Granted, neither is probably what was intended...

Comment: @user3611379: What is your intent for that xor statement? As N8TRO alluded to, you're trying to xor a 2-bit vector with a single bit (my comment above was meant to point out that this was strictly legal if you're using VHDL-2008, not that it's *correct* per your intent). What is the operation you are trying to perform?

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems.  Firstly your assignment operator `<=` should always be to the right of the signal that's being assigned.  So for the lines:

```
(others=>'0')<=data;
(others=>'0')<=CD;
```

Change it to:

```
data <= (others=>'0');
CD <= (others=>'0')
```

Also as N8TRO suggested, you can't use xor on a vector input.  You would need to access each bit of data individually.

As BrianDrummond pointed out, Assignment Symbol is a more appropriate name for `:=` and `<=`

Comment: There IS no assignment operator in VHDL! "Operator" in VHDL (and Ada) has a specific meaning closely related to the mathematical meaning; and Assignment has characteristics which lie outside that meaning. Important distinction: as such, you cannot embed an assignment inside an expression; assignment is a statement. "Assignment symbol" would be a better term for `:=` or `<=`

Comment: Apparently so was the author of that webpage... it's amazing where you see references to "assignment operator" creeping in from languages where assignment is thought of as an operator, but it's (IMO) worth maintaining precision and clarity of language.

Comment: To be precise, you *can* use `xor` on a vector. Prior to VHDL-2008, you couldn't `xor` a bit with a vector (natively), but those overloads were added to the standard.

Comment: @fru1tbat, indeed, it is supported in VHDL-2008, but I'd be very careful using anything in VHDL-2008 without absolutely assuring that the vendor you're using... cough xilinx... cough... actually can synthesize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
com(i)<= not(CD(i)xor(data) )
```

`data` is 2 bits wide - are you expecting the compiler to XOR `data` with the single bit of `CD(i)`?

As pointed out in the comments, VHDL2008 supports XORing vectors in two ways:

- as a unary operator (which is not what is being asked for in the OP),
- XORing a vector with a single bit, returning a vector.

Neither of which quite matches the code at the top...

Comment: As I've commented in other places here, that is supported in VHDL-2008, is it not? The target of the assignment would seem to be the actual problem, not the operands.

Comment: in 2008, you can xor a single bit with a vector, which returns a vector, or you can "reduction xor" (unary) just a vector, which returns a bit. Not sure what the intent of the original code was - just wanted to make sure your answer was not misinterpreted.

Comment: @fru1tbat: "you can xor a single bit with a vector, which returns a vector" - that bit I'd missed, thanks!  another edit...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code. See Martin's and Russell's answers for the more critical ones. In addition:

1. You should probably reverse the order of your for-loop and the `if (clk'event ...` statement in your process, the way you have commented out. i.e.:

   ```
   if rst = '1' then
     ...
   elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
     for i in 0 to 3 loop
       ...
     end loop;
   end if;
   ```

   It will probably work the other way, but it's nonstandard.
2. Either way, `i` is not in scope where you're trying to use it outside the process (in the statement `s<=com(i);`). If you mean to assign `com` directly to `s`, you can just write `s <= com;`. As indicated in other answers, you have some problems with your vector widths regarding your `xor` statement, so I'm not sure what your intent is.

And as alluded to elsewhere, the error you see is telling you that you're trying to use `data` (a 2-bit vector) with an operator (`xor`) that expects a single bit (e.g., `std_ulogic`). I've made a point elsewhere on this question to be precise about what is and isn't legal, especially with VHDL-2008 (with the disclaimer that I'm mostly just being picky), but even if you were using VHDL-2008 (which that error seems to indicate you are not), the result of the operation would be a vector, and you're attempting to assign it to a single bit (`com(i)`). How you fix this line depends on what your intent for your code is.